# How to export data from firebase by using 'curl'

Tags: curl, firebase, export

According to the documentation, it is said:

You can go to your Firebase App Dashboard and export all of your data in JSON format. You can also export it via the REST API:

```
curl "https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/.json?print=pretty&auth=<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP-SECRET>"
```

However, when i use this in terminal, it all printed out inside the terminal and part of it did not show up because terminal only show limited lines.

Is there any way I can export data from firebase to a file?

Thanks!

Comment: You can redirect the output to a file by adding `> export.json` to your command.

Comment: That works!, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that worked for me.

`curl "https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/.json?print=pretty&auth=<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP-SECRET>  > [json-file-name].json"`

Example:

`curl 'https://proj-name.firebaseio.com/repository/users.json?print=pretty' > data.json`